# Return row with values if nothing fits the conditions

Tags: iseries

I have his query that works fine, but I need it to return a line when nothing is found to suit the conditions:

```
SELECT D.CODPRO, D.VALPRO, COALESCE(SUM(d.UVCLIV), 0)  AS SUM 
FROM FGE50LM0TV.GESUPE E LEFT JOIN FGE50LM0TV.GESUPD D   
ON E.NUMSUP=D.NUMSUP AND E.SNUSUP=D.SNUSUP               
WHERE E.CODACT = '001'                                         
AND D.CODPRO <> ''                                       
AND E.CIRPIC = 'HUB'                                     
AND E.ETASUP IN ('30','40','60')                         
AND D.CNFLIG = '2'                                       
AND E.TOPMNQ <> '1'                                      
AND D.CODPRO IN ('TST UOP 1')                                 
GROUP BY D.CODACT, D.CODPRO, D.VALPRO
```

Maybe the question is not that clear.
Let me simplify it:

I want the following query to return the CODPRO, VALPRO, 0 as SUM of UVCLIV when CNFLIG is <> of '2':

```
SELECT CODPRO, VALPRO, COALESCE(SUM(UVCLIV), 0)  AS SUM 
FROM FGE50LM0TV.GESUPD                              
WHERE CNFLIG = '2'                                                                          
AND CODPRO IN ('TST UOP 1')                                 
GROUP BY CODACT, CODPRO, VALPRO ;
```

This is what I have for this product now in the table:

[image]

I use this query to insert a line of PRODUCT, VARIANT, QUANTITY into a file (H) by making a sum of all lines with that PRODUCT/VARIANT from another file (D). I have all those conditions that I wrote, and I want to receive a line with the PRODUCT, VARIANT, 0 as SUM for the situation when the SQL does not find anything according to my conditions.

I am not using MySQL workbench. I am on an IBM Emulator Utility v 14.14

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that

- for the subset where `CODPRO IN ('TST UOP 1')`, the `FGE50LM0TV.GESUPD` dataset has all the combinations of `CODPRO, VALPRO` that you want;
- not all of the combinations match the additional condition of `CNFLIG = '2'`;
- you would like to obtain the sums for all those combinations, including the ones that do not have `CNFLIG = '2'`.

If my understanding is correct, then you could just remove the `CNFLIG = '2'` condition from the `WHERE` clause and use it inside `SUM` as part of a `CASE` expression, like this:

```
SELECT
  CODPRO
, VALPRO
, COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN CNFLIG = '2' THEN UVCLIV END), 0)  AS SUM
FROM
  FGE50LM0TV.GESUPD
WHERE
  CODPRO IN ('TST UOP 1')                            
GROUP BY
  CODACT
, CODPRO
, VALPRO
;
```

This way you are not simply getting the sum of `UVCLIV`.  You are including `UVCLIV` in the sum only if `CNFLIG` is `'2'`.  Otherwise the expression evaluates to null and the `SUM` function omits it.  If a particular row group has no single row matching that condition, the `SUM` will return null, but your `COALESCE` is there to turn it into a 0.

Comment: Actually this work. What I don't understand is why if I change to "CODPRO in (SELECT VALUE FROM FGE50LM0TV.SVINVD) it does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i get your question right. Just reverse the where clauses one by one like below. This should work:

```
SELECT D.CODPRO, D.VALPRO, COALESCE(SUM(d.UVCLIV), 0)  AS SUM 
FROM FGE50LM0TV.GESUPE E LEFT JOIN FGE50LM0TV.GESUPD D   
ON E.NUMSUP=D.NUMSUP AND E.SNUSUP=D.SNUSUP               
WHERE E.CODACT <> '001'                                         
AND D.CODPRO = ''                                       
AND E.CIRPIC <> 'HUB'                                     
AND E.ETASUP NOT IN ('30','40','60')                         
AND D.CNFLIG <> '2'                                       
AND E.TOPMNQ = '1'                                      
AND D.CODPRO NOT IN ('TST UOP 1')                                 
GROUP BY D.CODACT, D.CODPRO, D.VALPRO
```

Comment: I added another more simple case.