# I need the identical lines to merge

Tags: iseries

Previous question: [Return row with values if nothing fits the conditions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/296218)

I almost got this working.
The problem that I have is that this variant of query does not merge the line from the SELECT with the one in the UNION if they are the same:

```
SELECT CODPRO, VALPRO, COALESCE(SUM(UVCLIV), 0)  AS SUM 
FROM FGE50LM0TV.GESUPD                              
WHERE CNFLIG = '2'                                                                          
AND CODPRO IN (SELECT VALINV FROM FGE50LM0TV.SVINVD WHERE NUMINV = 59)                                 
GROUP BY CODACT, CODPRO, VALPRO 
UNION (SELECT VALINV, 0, 0 FROM FGE50LM0TV.SVINVD WHERE NUMINV = 59) ;
```

This is what SVINVD looks like:

[image]

This is what GESUPD looks like:

[image]

No line for "PRODUIT5" here.

So in consequence I get a doubled line:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `UNION` operator eliminates duplicate rows.  It means that two rows will merge only if they are completely identical.  Row

| CODPRO | VALPRO | SUM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PRODUCT3 | 0 | 212 |

will not merge with row

| CODPRO | VALPRO | SUM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PRODUCT3 | 0 | 0 |

because the values in the last column differ.

Anyway, if the goal is to complete the set returned by

```
SELECT CODPRO, VALPRO, COALESCE(SUM(UVCLIV), 0)  AS SUM
FROM FGE50LM0TV.GESUPD
WHERE CNFLIG = '2'
AND CODPRO IN (SELECT VALINV FROM FGE50LM0TV.SVINVD WHERE NUMINV = 59)
```

with missing values found in

```
SELECT VALINV FROM FGE50LM0TV.SVINVD WHERE NUMINV = 59
```

then there are a few approaches to this.

#### 1. `UNION` + `EXCEPT`

```
SELECT CODPRO, VALPRO, COALESCE(SUM(UVCLIV), 0)  AS SUM
FROM FGE50LM0TV.GESUPD
WHERE CNFLIG = '2'
AND CODPRO IN (SELECT VALINV FROM FGE50LM0TV.SVINVD WHERE NUMINV = 59)
UNION
(
SELECT VALINV, 0, 0 FROM FGE50LM0TV.SVINVD WHERE NUMINV = 59
EXCEPT
SELECT CODPRO, 0, 0 FROM FGE50LM0TV.GESUPD WHERE CNFLIG = '2'
)
```

There are repetitive bits of logic here, like the `CNFLIG = '2'` – an aspect which I personally prefer to avoid in my queries if possible.  Other than that, this seems like more or less straightforward approach to me.

#### 2. `LEFT JOIN`

Use your query as a derived table and outer-join it to `FGE50LM0TV.SVINVD`.  Substitute 0 for missing rows' `VALPRO` and `SUM`.  Like this:

```
SELECT
  s.VALINV AS CODPRO, COALESCE(g.VALPRO, 0) AS VALPRO, COALESCE(g.SUM, 0) AS SUM
FROM
  FGE50LM0TV.SVINVD AS s
  LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      CODPRO, VALPRO, COALESCE(SUM(UVCLIV), 0)  AS SUM
    FROM
      FGE50LM0TV.GESUPD
    WHERE
      CNFLIG = '2'
  ) AS g ON s.VALINV = g.CODPRO
WHERE
  s.NUMINV = 59
;
```

#### 3. `LEFT JOIN`, Alternative Option

You can also try outer-joining `FGE50LM0TV.GESUPD` to `FGE50LM0TV.SVINVD` directly, and then apply the grouping:

```
SELECT
  s.VALINV AS CODPRO, COALESCE(g.VALPRO, 0) AS VALPRO, COALESCE(SUM(g.UVCLIV), 0) AS SUM
FROM
  FGE50LM0TV.SVINVD AS s
  LEFT JOIN FGE50LM0TV.GESUPD AS g ON s.VALINV = g.CODPRO AND g.CNFLIG = '2'
WHERE
  s.NUMINV = 59
GROUP BY
  s.VALINV, g.VALPRO
;
```

Note that the `CNFLIG = '2'` is moved from `WHERE` to the `ON` clause.  This is so as to avoid eliminating non-matching `GESUPD` entries.  The `WHERE` clause applies to the entire joined set, and where `GESUPD` has no match for `SVINVD`, the `CNFLIG = '2'` would completely exclude that row from the output, contrary to what you are trying to achieve.  In the `ON` clause, however, the condition would apply to `GESUPD` only, and `SVINVD` rows that have no match would still be returned.

While generally looking simpler than the other `LEFT JOIN` solution, this option may not necessarily be as fast.  You will have to test both to compare the performance for yourself.  Naturally, that goes for all three options.

Comment: Thank u so much. They all work really fine